# How do I run parallel actions in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

How do I run a parallel action `(process)` to the main app in Android?

I know that, there are a lot of ways to do it: `Threads`, `Tasks`, `Handlers` and etc'...
This is the way I chose. But I think it takes a lot of memory and doesn't closes in the interrupt call.

```
checkReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Check is this a good way to handle threads
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    internetConnectionManager.TryConnect();
                    this.interrupt();
                }
            };
            t.start();                  
        }               
    }
};
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `this.interrupt` won't compile. I believe you meant to call something like `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`. Also, do you need to receive result when `TryConnect()` is finsied ?

Comment: No, I don't need a result. I only need to run this function

Comment: I use to use AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things wrong with your arroach:

- You **should not** start a thread in `onRecieve` method. The reason is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) :

> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an
>   onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at
>   that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the
>   system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation
>   completes

- Second, calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` does not make any sense in your example since your thread is already done by that line and will finish, and also because you don not check `interrupted` flag anyway.

**The better way**, in my opinion, would be to start a simple [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) from your `onReceive` code. [Here is](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) a simple tutorial.

**Important edit** based on *FunkTheMonk*'s comment: 
If the broadcast comes from an alarm or external event, it is possible that your device will go to sleep shortly after `onReceive` returns (even if you create a service). If that is the case, instead of using regular `BroadCastReceiver` you should extend [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) from support library.

Comment: Also worth noting that if the broadcast comes from an alarm or external event, it is possible that your device will go to sleep shortly after onReceive returns (even if you create a thread or service) - a helper class is available in the support library: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: My broadcast does come from alarm(manager). So what should I do?

Comment: @FunkTheMonk I inlined your comment in my answer almost verbatim, hope you don't mind. Thanks for pointing this out, I never thought of it myself before.

Comment: In my alarm I use RTC_WAKEUP, In this case I also need WakefulBroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @AlexKapustian: Yes, for `_WAKEUP`-style alarms, you nee to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or my `WakefulIntentService`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: I have a problem...I can't pass and object to intetservice...
It's too complicated to serialize it and too many objects to make them parcable...any other options?

Comment: @Alex It is straightforward to make your class implement **parcelable**, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/2358786) Then you can put your object into intent and extract it in your service, this is the normal way. Alternatively if your object logically represents globally accessed state, or could be made a singleton, you could make it globally accessible to all your components.

Comment: what if I have a nested object inside my object, does it also needs to be parcelable?

Comment: @Alex Yes, normally it should be parcelable as well. I guess you had figured that out already since you accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use handler

if you want to stop handler then fire an intent with some value eg.("quit handler")to receiver
and call remove call back and inside handler you can handle the rest using ACTION switch
you can also use intentservice

Comment: Handlers aren't asynchronous unless you have have multiple handlers tied to loopers created for different threads.. Messages posted to a single Handler are handled one at a time, if one blocks, the rest will have to wait